# Trying to pass accountlist or account ID from aura to apex but, apex shows that as null

Tags: aura

Trying to pass accountlist or account ID from aura to apex but, apex shows that as null

Here is my code.

Aura:

```
<aura:attribute name="accountList" type="Account[]"/>    
           <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountList}" var="acc" indexVar="index"
                <l_lookup:Lookup aura:id="acctLookup" 
                                    objectType="Account" 
                                    selectedRecordId="{!acc.Id}"
                                    isRequired="{!v.requireAccountLookup}"
                                    primarySearchField="Name" 
                                    additionalField="PersonEmail"
                                    fuzzySearch="true"
                                    helpText="This person account will be used as the new buyer"
                                    queryCondition="IsPersonAccount = true" orderBy="Name" 
          withSharing="false"
    </aura:iteration>
```

JS:

```
var accountIds = new Array();
         var accounts = component.get("v.accountList");
    for(var i=0;i<accounts.length;i++){
        accountIds.push(accounts[i].id);
    }
    
    action.setParams({
        quoteId : component.get("v.recordId"),
        connectionId : component.get("v.simpleRecord.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c"),
        newBuyerAccountId : JSON.stringify(accountIds),
        reason : component.get("v.reason")
    });
```

Apex:

```
 public static BuyerChangeResultWrapper handleAddedBuyers(Id quoteId, Id connectionId, String newBuyerAccountId, String reason){
    BuyerChangeResultWrapper bcrw = new BuyerChangeResultWrapper();
    List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();
    /*for(Account acc:newBuyerAccountId){
        system.debug('accouunt id'+acc.id);
        accountIds.add(acc.id);
    }
    system.debug('accouunt list'+accountIds);*/
    Type ArrType = Type.forName('List<String>');
    accountIds = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(newBuyerAccountId, ArrType);
    List<Account> acctList = [SELECT Id, PersonContactId, Full_Legal_Name__pc FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accountIds];
```

above query is returning null because the method parameter newBuyerAccountId is null.

Comment: You can pass array as it is without stringify and have parameter List<String> accountIds. Why are you even stringifying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small mistake.

In js, where you are creating the array "accountIds" just update the `accounts[i].id` to `accounts[i].Id` because javascript is a case sensitive language thus 'id' and 'Id' differs.

```
 for(var i=0;i<accounts.length;i++){
     accountIds.push(accounts[i].Id);
 }
```

Note - You can also pass the array of account ids itself to apex as `List<String>`

Comment: Awesome. That worked.